# SQLite VS2013 Entity Framework 6 InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, sqlite, visual-studio-2013

I'm still quite new to Entity Framework, that's maybe why I'm close to pulling my hair out already (came from Windows Forms).

I'm creating a WPF app with the use of SQLite and EF 6 in VS2013, target framework is v. 4.5.

I'm using database first approach. I created a SQLite database using Server Explorer Tool of VS2013. Then I added ADO.NET Entity Data Model to my project from the existing database (in the wizard I checked - Include foreign keys and Pluralize or Singularize object names). The wizard created for me "TemplateDataModel.edmx". My DbContext is called "TemplateEntities". 
My problem is this. I instantiate the context:

```
this.m_DB = new TemplateEntities();
```

When I want to get a list of records from a data table called "Operation" I use this code:

```
this.m_DB.Operations.ToList<Operation>()
```

Calling this method always throws InvalidCastException. The code of Operation class (generated by VS) is this:

```
public partial class Operation
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Operation()
    {
        this.ParameterSets = new HashSet<ParameterSet>();
    }

    public long ID { get; set; }
    public long OperationPLC_ID { get; set; }
    public string OperationIdentifier { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime ChangedOnDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsInUse { get; set; }
    public string OperationContent { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<ParameterSet> ParameterSets { get; set; }
}
```

I'm pretty sure that I only have 1 "Operation" class defined in the project's namespace.
The strange thing is that querying other tables works nicely. It's only this table that I can't query. Other methods of the DbSet also throw InvalidCastException, e.g.

```
this.m_DB.Operations.First<Operation>()
```

I should also say that I had a problem installing EF and make it work with the SQLite at first. I had to perform a work-around which I found here on this forum. I switched my project to target .NET Framework v. 4.0, then I installed EF using NuGet package manager and then I switched the project back to v. 4.5 (because I use ribbon in the GUI which seems to be unavailable in .NET 4.0).

Thank you for any advice.

As I mentioned below, it works now.
@Sergey L - yes I changed data in the table. Actually I started removing columns from the Operation table one by one until I only had one column - ID column. Then it worked. Then I started adding the columns back. After each added column a deleted the entire data model and re-created it using Visual Studio's Add "ADO.NET Entity Data Model" function.

@Sergey L - I don't know how to pull a SQL definition from the Server Explorer of Visual Studio, but the screen shot of the table design is here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKpxO.png)

Comment: Are you sure the `Operation` type in your `ToList` is from your model and not some class in another namespace?

Comment: The `Operation` class generated by VS is located in namespace `PanelDeploymentTool`. In my code `this.m_DB.Operations.ToList<Operation>()` when I hover the mouse on `Operation` word, a tooltip in IDE displays the text "class PanelDeploymentTool.Operation". Based on that I conclude that it's the right class. I'll be happy to post other information if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it, although I still don't know what the cause was.

1. I opened the data model in Model Browser.
2. I removed all columns from my `Operation` entity except 1 column - the ID.
3. Then it worked.
4. I started adding the columns back one by one.
5. My `Operation` entity (class) looks like this now:

   ```
   public partial class Operation
   {
   [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
   public Operation()
   {
       this.ParameterSets = new HashSet<ParameterSet>();
   }

   public long ID { get; set; }
   public long OperationPLC_ID { get; set; }
   public string OperationIdentifier { get; set; }
   public System.DateTime ChangedOn { get; set; }
   public bool IsInUse { get; set; }
   public bool DoesTCApply { get; set; }
   public string OperationContent { get; set; }

   [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
   public virtual ICollection<ParameterSet> ParameterSets { get; set; }
   ```

   }

It works.

Comment: Have you changed any data in the Operation table? What is sql definition of the table?